# PHP cURL CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER not passing header

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

I am unable to pass HTTP headers in cURL via PHP.

I am able to set cookies, url, etc. but I cannot seem to set anything via CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Crawlera-Cookies: disable';

$cookies = "test=1234; path=/";

curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_URL,                $url);
curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,         $headers);
curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER,             1);
curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,     1);
curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_USERAGENT,          'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_COOKIE,             $cookies);
```

Which outputs the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2015 19:28:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Amazon) PHP/5.6.10
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.10
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

As you can see, I am running on an AWS EC2 instance running PHP 5.6.10.

Thank you!

Comment: `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` sets request headers. You're showing us response headers.